# Microcontroller vs FPGA to DAC and ADC

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, adc, raspberry-pi, dac

I searched multiple forums about microcontrollers and FPGAs but I couldn't find the answer were I was looking for.

I have to make a choice of whether I'm going to use a microcontroller/minipc like a Rapsberry Pi or something like a Zynq SoC.

What I want to do is: detect vibrations with a geophone sensor, use an ADC to send the information to a controller, then use a DAC to send a counter signal towards an actuator.

I would still like to be able to display the incoming and outgoing signals and tune the outgoing signal in a way that I can counter a specific frequency.

Currently I'm using a fanless pc, some amplifiers, DAC and ADC to do the computations and a external laptop to tune the signal (with MATLAB).

Now, I Would like to come up with a solution to use a smaller way to do the calculations.
I checked the Rapsberry Pi, but the range in Volts for the DAC - ADC are very low: -0.3 to +0.3V. I'm looking for a range between +/-10V and 16 bit.

Also, I still need to be able to tune and display the signals. Maybe two chips, one for calculations and one for communication to the user interface?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean here: "would still like to be able to display the incoming and outgoing signals and tune the outgoing signal in a way that I can counter a specific frequency"? When you say "counter", do you mean count? Or something else?

Comment: Hi DiBosco, thank you for your question. I do mean counter. To remove a specific frequency. So imagine there is a spike on 40 Hz by a fan or something. Then I would like to counter this. Countermeasure

Comment: @Dukel There is nowhere near enough information in your question to provide answers. Sampling rates, resolution, components etc will be needed, and even then your question is very very broad.

Comment: The Raspberry pi does not have any ADC/DACs. Thus you will always need to use an external module, which means you are free to choose one with the right voltage range.

Comment: I think that what you need to use to do this depends on the maths you are carrying out in your processor. If you think the Pi will do the requisite maths you can  interface with external ADCs and DACs. It also depends on how many of these you want to make. I think it's maybe too broad a question as it stands and probably not enough information. You might get away with a Cortex M4 or M7, I think it's probably impossible to say with the info we have.

Comment: If you use a zynq, who is going to provide you with the logic for the FPGA?

Comment: The deciding factor would be what maximum latency you can tolerate between analog input and analog output.

Comment: The way you asked you question suggests that you should go for the Raspberry. Also terms like Geophone ad Vibrations (seemingly those of the ground) suggest that your need for Sampling rate is way under 1M. Don't overestimate your demands. You'll probably be good with a Raspi for all tasks including some FFT for the visualisation part. For the onboard audio ADC you might want to use a simple voltage divider. But be aware that the onboard codec is not known to be the most accurate and of course ment for audio so sample rate is limited.

Comment: Raspberry Pi can use USB audio soundcard as ADC/DAC for better quality.

Comment: Note that "send a counter signal to the actuator" is a classic control systems problem - you may be able to achieve this without going through the digital domain at all. Whatever you do, latency is going to be a very important consideration. How much delay can you accept between receiving the signal and sending to the actuator?

Comment: I will look into the ADC/DAC modules for the Raspberry pi, thanks. 4kHz is already enough so FPGA will indeed be overkill.
Thank you! I think the Raspberry pi or something of a sort will do.

Comment: @Dukel Glad to see the rate FINALLY mentioned! This is one of those cases where you already have a solution running and could have provided LOTS OF DETAILS about what is working for you. Data rates, DAC and ADC precisions, details on the processing steps required (algorithms and ordering) all of which would have made an answer more applicable and directed to your needs. Also have a look at quad-core units like the ODROID-C2, which run at several GHz, too. Should you need something really fast and cheap.

Comment: @jonk thank you for you advice. Some specifications are nog clear yet, so I was maybe hoping to get some suggestions. The ODROID-C2 is looking good, I will read in to that, thanks again!

Comment: I asked about latency because SBCs like the Pi are not real time systems, you have to account for the OS using a bit of cpu time, so if you need a 1 millisecond input to output latency in hard real time, headaches occur. Also the audio ADCs and DACs use buffered IO, and the latency is like 1 buffer, or 1 USB frame, so this also adds delay. A fast microcontroller, on the other hand, can process each sample as it comes, which gives much lower latency. But you must know the latency you need first...

Answer (score 4):

As I see it, you have 3 options:

## PC, scaled down

Keep using the same system, just scale it down. This is easy (because you have a high-level system), but maybe not too efficient since the operating system is not optimised for latency or real-time operation. It will also be power-hungry.

## MCU

A microcontroller running at ~100 MHz ought to have plenty of processing power for this task (and will be far more responsive than a linux based solution). You will need to interface to the peripheral voltage levels, but should be able to use a simple amplifier for the task (providing some protection for the digital side in the process). You can capture output data over a UART, some indicator lights or a small display panel - all of these parts should be easy to find examples for. Of course, you have to learn a slightly different software paradigm (micro-python is possible, but maybe not ideal here).

## FPGA

Your example part might not be a good fit - it is hugely over-specified and expensive. The basic real-time processing could likely be done in a fairly small device, but the low level coding is likely to be a challenge (unless matlab can generate you all the code you need).

---

Using FPGA here would typically be the approach to use if the calculations are complex and demanding. An MCU ought to be a good fit if your aim is to scale down the hardware, and maybe make it battery powered. Plenty of small MCUs come on credit-card sized development boards at ~$10.

Check what data rate you need in order to generate your 'canceling' signal, this will determine the memory array size and DMA frequency that you need to drive the DAC in your design.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a ±10V range, this is typically outside the range of most ADC's and DACs, so you would need an off the shelf solution, or design your own analog system.

Use a raspberri pi, they are cheap and there are numerous code examples and tutorials to get you started, the software is free and most distros that you put on a rasberri pi already come with software that you will use. You can also get [DAQ's that work in the ±10V range](https://hackaday.io/project/18583-pidaq-a-raspberry-pi-data-aquisition-module)

A microcontroller (on a dev board) is also an option, however make sure the software (compiler) is free. You can use gcc with most, but if you want to debug with an IDE this becomes harder because most commercial compilers limit you to 32kbytes of programming before the cost rises into the thousands. Most likely you will be programming in C. Unless you can find a shield you would design your own electronics on a PCB. With a microcontroller you will be able to run a control loop faster than a PC or a device with a regular operating system (you might be able put an Real Time Operating System (RTOS) on a pi, and run things faster.)

An FPGA is the most complicated, the toolchains are free, but the time you will take to set up the software could be days for a starter. There are dev boards, the analog electronics would need to be designed. The tradeoff is speed, if you have very fast signals, then you would need to use an FPGA because you can design hardware on the gate level with ns timing.

Comment: Keil has a code-size limit for the compiler, but will debug a larger image no problem. True, I don't know if it can use GCC debug info...

Comment: Eclipse for C/C++ can be used to debug bare-metal ARM GCC for free with no code size restriction

Comment: You can debug with GCC from the command line if you desire, I suppose Eclipse can hook into this